# Cocoa : Subviews appearence within inactive window

Tags: cocoa, window, focus, subview, nstabview

When an application window is active (close button is red and window title is black), the subviews (NSTabViews, scrollers..) show the active element in blue. But when the application is inactive (close button and window title are grey), the subviews show the active element in grey. It's the behavior of Xcode with its mainwindow scroller.

But applications like the character viewer have a different behavior. When they are inactive (another app window is active with the focus), the subviews keep the active element in blue.

How can we obtain this behavior ?

Nota : I work without Interface Builder.

Thanks

Comment: Is NSPanel what you're looking for?

Comment: I'm using a NSWindow, but I can replace it by a NSPanel. Do you know a method to obtain this behavior with NSPanel ?

Answer (score 0):

See NSColor.h

Colors with the word "inactive" in them are used to draw Nscontrols when window is inactive.  My Nscell subclasses call [[[self controlview] window]   iskeywindow] and then choose the appropriate color to draw.

Comment: If I understand your answer, I need to subclass all my NSControl to set its color when the window become keyWindow ? I don't think that the Apple programmers or others will take the time to make subclass of all NSControls. I don't want to use a specific color, I just want my NSControl to keep is blue appearance when the window is inactive. There might be a global property to acheive that.